# How to show an element on other elemnts?

Tags: wpf

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition  ></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Expander  >
          <Border Background="Green" Height="50" Width="150"></Border>
       </Expander>
        <Button Content="ok" Height="20" Grid.Row="1"   VerticalAlignment="Top"></Button>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ummmm if I understand you correctly, you want to have your Expander on top of your Button?

In that case, just have both controls share the same grid cell. You will probably have to adjust your Button's margins or alignment to position it correctly

```
<Grid>
      <Expander Canvas.ZIndex="0">
          <Border Background="Green" Height="50" Width="150"></Border>
      </Expander>

      <Button Canvas.ZIndex="1" Content="ok" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,30,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is There any way that  the controls isn't in  share grid cell?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a canvas here as your parent container. Using a canvas you can use the SetZIndex method to change the Z index of various child controls, which causes one control to render in front of/"over" another control.

See [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setzindex%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on the method